# Number Theory: Legendre Symbols

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I have the following question.

> Calculate the Legendre symbol $\bigl(\frac{77}{5^{200}+1}\bigr)$.

I know the following: $5^6\equiv1\pmod7$, $5^{10}\equiv1\pmod{11}$. Thus I approached this problem as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{77}{5^{200}+1}\right) & = & \left(\frac{7}{5^{200}+1}\right)\left(\frac{11}{5^{200}+1}\right)\\\\
 & = & \left(\frac{5^{200}+1}{7}\right)\left(\frac{5^{200}+1}{11}\right)\\\\
 & = & \left(\frac{5^{(6)33+2}+1}{7}\right)\left(\frac{5^{(20)(10)}+1}{11}\right)\\\\
 & = & \left(\frac{25+1}{7}\right)\left(\frac{1+1}{11}\right)\\\\
 & = & \left(\frac{26}{7}\right)\left(\frac{2}{11}\right)\\\\
 & = & \left(\frac{5}{7}\right)(-1)=(-1)\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)=(-1)\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)\\\\
 & = & (-1)(-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=1
\end{eqnarray}

I am skeptical about my answer because of the beginning part where I flipped the Legendre symbol. Any suggestion?

Thank you for your time and thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: That isn't right. $5^{200}+1$ is even, and the Legendre symbol requires the "denominator" to be an odd prime. Even for the Jacobi symbol, the "denominator" must be odd. It could be the [Kronecker symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol).

Comment: The professor specifically said it was a Legendre symbol. That being said, where did I go wrong, and how do I approach it?

Comment: She/he is wrong.

Comment: Then how do I go about deducing this problem?

Comment: The kronecker symbol $77|5^{200}+1$ is indeed $1$, also the symbol $5^{200}+1|77$. PARI does not seem to use the factorization of $5^{200}+1$, which would take quite a while. There must be some method to calculate the kronecker symbol without knowing the factors of $5^{200}+1$, but I do not know how this works.

Comment: I would probably write your last step as:

=(-1)(-1)
= 1 

Because $(\frac{2}{5})$ = -1 since 5 $\equiv$ 5 mod 8 $\equiv$ -3 mod 8.